# Display ObservableCollection of class with string property in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection` of my `Movie` class which has a string property name `Name`, I want it to be displayed in a `DataGrid` in WPF.

```
<Window x:Class="MovieList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MovieList"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Movie List" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding movies}" AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MovieList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Movie> movies;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            movies = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\")) {
                movies.Add(new Movie(dir));
            }

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Movie(string movieName)
        {
            Name = movieName;
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind to fields, make `movies` a `public` property, like `public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies { get; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [cannot bind to fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), make `movies` a `public` property and use pascal casing as per convention.

```
public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies { get; }
```

You create your `Movies` collection in code-behind, but bindings work on the `DataContext` that is inherited from parent controls all the way up to your window, where it is unset. You can set it there:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Or you can use a relative source with ancestor type to refer to the window in the `ItemsSource` binding.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Movies, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindowWindow}}}"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Gray">
```

Since the `DataGrid` auto-generates columns from properties of the bound type by default, you do not have to create columns yourself. However, if you want to, set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns?view=net-5.0) to `false`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Gray"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you miss that, you will have duplicate columns, the auto-generated ones and your own.

Answer (score 2):

public ObservableCollection Movies {get;}

Comment: It helps if you explain a bit about what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

Make `movies` a public property in MainWindow:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies {get; private set;}
```

In XAML, bind the DataContext of the window to itself and then bind the grid:

```
<Window x:Class="MovieList.MainWindow"
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
   ...
   >
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding movies}" AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" >
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding ="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```